# Why lucene query returns nothing?

Tags: solr, lucene

Why the following lucene query returns zero hits on following documents?
Lucene:

```
title:#billa content:#billa user:#billaindex
```

documents:

```
"helis_insta: #iceage #sit #billa #kuscheltier"
"paulii_danii:    Mandala  \n#schmetterling #gewinnspiel #billa  #blühendesösterreich    #malen #filzstifte" 
"nora_hoeg: So. Jetzt amoi ehrlich: wer hat da von wem abgeschrieben?! #vienna #billa #merkur #wurst #saussage #bbq    #summer #creative #graphicdesign #oiswurscht"
```

Comment: Is that the "content" fields of three documents, or what?  What does your analyzer look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `schema.xml` you should check the Analyzer/Tokenizer setting.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

There could be different reasons, like the tokenizer splits `#billa` into `#` and `billa` or the stemmer on index-time removes the `#` while there is no stemming on query time.

(Analyzer/Tokenizer should be the same on index and query time)